Is it possible to configure Firebase so that when you disable a user, their token expires?
I am using Firebase for authentication in my web application. In the application it is quite common that the owner can disable accounts. For security reasons, when a user is disabled, they should be removed from the platform. Testing, when I disable an account, the user cannot log in, but if they are already on the platform, they will not be removed from the platform (I suppose until the token expires). Is it possible to configure that when you deactivate a user, they are immediately removed from their account?

Once it is minted, a JWT is valid until the expiration time in that token. While you can revoke a refresh token, there is no way to invalidate an ID token before its expiration time.
What you can do is keep a list of revoked tokens somewhere, and then check that list before granting access to a resource. To learn more about this, check out the Firebase documentation on detecting ID token revocation.
This question has come up quite a few times before, so I recommend also checking out:

Firebase deleted user is able to change data. How can I fix this without modifying application code?
Deleted user has access to Firebase Firestore
When a Firebase user is deleted from Firebase console (after user login), it is not reflected in the application
and more questions about deleted user can retaining access


Hi Frank. I understand that these tokens have a duration of 1 hour, right? So, I could revoke the refresh token for that user and this user would simply have access until the duration of the current token runs out (maximum 1 hour), am I correct? Maybe that will be enough for us.
By the way, then, when disabling the user, the refresh token is not automatically disabled? It should not be like that?

I'm just a little confused with the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens. I'm not sure if it is automatically disabled or not when the user is disabled.

Comment #1) Correct. A disabled user won't be able to mint new ID tokens, so once their current ID token expires they'll lose access. --- Comment 2) Yes, disabling a user is all that you need to do. There's no need to then also explicitly delete the refresh token.

Thank you very much Frank for your help. Whenever I ask something related to Firebase I wait for your answer haha
